# Trying to insert variables from two lists into strings - how do I do it?

Tags: python, string, list

So I have the following code:

```
optionlist =  [
        '<option value="id=%s+%s">%s - %s</option>' %
        (x, y, x, y) for x in numlist, y in numlist2
        ]
```

What I would like is for the values from `x` to be inserted in the first `%s`, values from `y` to be inserted in the second `%s`, the same value from `x` to be inserted in the third, and the same value from `y` to be inserted in the fourth `%s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
['<option value="id=%s+%s">%s - %s</option>' % (x, y, x, y) for x, y in zip(numlist, numlist2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

```
In [1]: l1 = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [3]: ['<option value="id={0}+{1}">{0} - {1}</option>'.format(i, j)
   ...:  for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]
Out[3]: 
['<option value="id=1+a">1 - a</option>',
 '<option value="id=2+b">2 - b</option>',
 '<option value="id=3+c">3 - c</option>']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
optionlist =  [
        '<option value="id=%s+%s">%s - %s</option>' %
        (x, y, x, y) for x, y in zip(numlist, numlist2)
        ]
```